# Why my call to node api including the path in react after proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am making an API call from homepage and the profile page, when it is called from homepage`http://localhost:3000/` it works fine and loads the data but when it is getting called from profile page `http://localhost:3000/profile` it is including /profile in the api call.

Like `http://localhost:5000/api/profile/posts/profile/username` while it should be only `http://localhost:5000/api/posts/profile/username`.

Please help

Api call code (username is coming from page props in profile page)

```
<div className="profileRightBottom">
    <Feed username="shivd" />
    <Rightbar profile />
</div>
```

```
const Feed = ({ username }) => {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = username
        ? await axios.get("posts/profile/" + username)
        : await axios.get("posts/timeline/63cf5546b59c8100a042538d");

      setPosts(res.data);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, [username]);
```

[image: I am using morgan to get this data]

I have also included the `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api"` in package.json file.

Comment: Have you verified that `username` has the value you think it does?

Comment: Yes , i have consoled it and it shows correct value

Comment: Well your code is using relative URLs. From the "profile" page, "profile/" is already part of the URL.

Comment: After reading your comment about relative urls, i added a base url in env and now it is working fine. Thanks.